# Why is data loaded bigger than expected using ADRP, ADD, and LDR instructions?

Tags: assembly, arm64, mach-o

I am learning assembly for Apple M1 arm64 and noticed something odd on trying to load a data from a label on the data segment.  It seems to be loading the content not just of the label I asked for `var1` but also the next label close to it `var2`.

```
.global _start

_start:
    mov x0, #0
    mov x1, #0

    // In this first part we load data from memory.
    // -------------

    // Load var1 from the memory, and set its address to X0 register.
    adrp X0, var1@PAGE      // address of var1 word 4k page
    add X0, X0, var1@PAGEOFF    // offset to var1 within the page

    // Get the value from the address memory stored on X0 register.
    // When using `ldr` with brackets loads the actual value
    // similar to dereferencing a pointer.
    ldr X1, [X0]

    // In this second part we update data from memory.
    // -------------

    // Set 3 to the X2 register.
    mov X2, #3     // <--- This is the line 38 where I add a breakpoint

    // Load the memory address for the vaX2 data variable.
    adrp X3, var2@PAGE
    add X3, X3, var2@PAGEOFF

    // Store X2 register value to the memory address on the X3 register.
    str X2, [X3]

    // Exit program
    mov X0, 0       // 0 status code
    mov X16, #1
    svc #0x80

.data
var1: .word 5
var2: .word 6
```

This is how I build it:

```bash
as lesson03.s -g -o lesson03.o
ld lesson03.o -o lesson03 -l System -syslibroot `xcrun -sdk macosx --show-sdk-path` -e _start -arch arm64
```

And this is how I am debugging the value for `X1`:

```bash
lldb lesson03

(lldb) b lesson03.s:38

Breakpoint 1: where = lesson03`start + 20, address = 0x0000000100003f8c
(lldb) run

(lldb) re read x1
      x1 = 0x0000000600000005
```

I was expecting to get `0x0000000000000005` (decimal `5`), but as we can see it was `0x0000000600000005` (decimal `25769803781`), which seems to be loading the data from `<var2=00000006,var1=00000005>` together.

Does anyone know why that happens and how to fix it? By the way, I am looking for a solution where I can still load data from the `.data` segment.

Comment: `.word` is 32 bit. Use `.quad`

Comment: Or use a 32-bit `w` register as the load destination, or a sign-extending 32-bit load into a 64-bit register.  (Look at C compiler output for how to do that, e.g. `long long foo(int *p) { return *p; }` on https://godbolt.org/z/M3P9qKbvW

Comment: Thanks so much @Jester and @PeterCordes, both solutions solved it. Is there a recommendation using one over another? I imagine for this case where I know it is a small number it would better use `.word` instead of `.quad` so there is less memory allocated.

Comment: Yes, generally use 32-bit integers when that's big enough; AArch64 has very good support for sign-extending and zero-extending when loading or even when using a narrow value in a register as an array index.  (Like sign-extending or zero-extending index addressing modes.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To mark this question as resolved, let me paraphrase Jester and Peter, who answered my question in the comments section.

The `.word` data directive holds 32-bit long data and I was loading that value into a `x` register which is 64-bit long. Therefore more data was being loaded into that register to completely fill it it up. To solve this issue I should either:

- Use `.quad` (64-bit) so both data and register match the same size.
- Or, still use `.word` (32-bit) but load the value to a `w` register which is 32-bit long as well.

References:

- [Data definition directives](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/101754/0622/armclang-Reference/armclang-Integrated-Assembler/Data-definition-directives)

Comment: The assembler also accepts `.xword` or `.8byte` for 64-bit data, either of which I would find more clear than `.quad`.  I believe `.quad` must come from x86-land, where "word" means 16 bits and so a 64-bit object is a "quadword".  But it's inconsistent with ARM terminology where "word" means 32 bits.